# Speakers stop working after plugging/unplugging headphones - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

I updated my laptop to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS with XFCE4 last year. Since then I've had the following problem:

After booting the machine the speakers function correctly - I can skype, listen to films, etc.
However if I plug in a pair of headphones and then unplug them again, the speakers stop working until after the next reboot.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem might be?

---

I've tried using `alsactl` in various ways, but so far no success. It's definitely a software problem - maybe a config gets changed somewhere?

Comment: No idea, but when the speakers are not anymore working, an `alsactl restore` might repair that.

Comment: Try to open the sound settings and select the speakers as a fallback device. I faced this problem too. It looks like a bug.

Comment: I am having the same issue, asked the question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314244/audio-stops-working-when-i-unplug-my-headphones-on-ubuntu-20-04 you can see my work around is to use pulseaudio to change the output device. But I still haven't been able to resolve this.