# Audio stops working when I unplug my headphones on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the issue linked.

When I boot my computer with my headphones plugged in, they are working. When I unplug them and plug back in they usually do not work.

To get it working again, I have installed `pavucontrol` "PulseAudio Volume Control". I go into "Configuration" and I under my audio controller, I change the Profile to "Analog Stereo Output" from "Off". It's almost as if it doesn't automatically detect the headphone being plugged in. there shouldn't be an issue with the hardware because it works fine on Windows with my dual boot.

How do I make it so that automatically it picks up that I have plugged in the headphones and switches the profile for me?

Edit: Following this does not fix the issue: [Ubuntu 18.04: Audio doesn't work unless I switch between outputs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165625/ubuntu-18-04-audio-doesnt-work-unless-i-switch-between-outputs), it is also a different scenario.

Edit: Looks like this is also a similar issue: [Speakers stop working after plugging/unplugging headphones - Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307405/speakers-stop-working-after-plugging-unplugging-headphones-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue, I have the same thing on Linux Mint 20.
When I was running ubuntu 20.10 I don't recall having this issue. On first plug in it works fine, I select headphones. If I remove and reinsert them in the combo jack no sound works. I have to go to sound settings and switch audio input devices back and forth and it works again. Hopefully that helps until someone more knowledgeable says something.